# Is it possible to stop Ruby scripts from importing Java in JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

From this page: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

In a Ruby script, if you use `require 'java'`, the script will be able to create things like `JFrame`s and such.

It may sound odd, but, is it possible, in any way, *to not allow such feature* (disable importing `Java`)?

---

If you are curious as to why am I asking, it is because I'm developing some kind of game engine on Java, but it allows users to script with Ruby to control the game logic - *only* the game logic. I don't want to give the freedom of creating `JFrame`s.

Comment: Even if you forbid Java, what stops the user from calling any other GUI library? Calling `sleep(10000000)`? Deleting the home directory?

Comment: you might check this thread out: http://ruby.11.n6.nabble.com/Prevent-Ruby-calling-Java-td3479685.html

Answer (score 1):

One hack would be to put 'java' into loaded features (the $" array). Requires would then assume it's already loaded and not try to load it again. A user could certainly remove it from that array, and try again, though.